# How can i cite a kaggle dataset in ieee conference paper?

Tags: publications, citations, ieee

I want to know how can I add a dataset link as a reference in the IEEE conference paper. I used a dataset for my works and then I described the dataset in the paper. But I don't know how to cite the Kaggle dataset as a reference.

Update:
I got a solution and here is the [link](https://www.kaggle.com/general/46091). There was a solution and that was:

**[Dataset creator's name]. ([Year & Month of dataset creation]). [Name of the dataset], [Version of the dataset]. Retrieved [Date Retrieved] from [URL of the dataset].**

Is this ok for IEEE conference format? Thank You.

Comment: A quick google search will lead you to a forum post on kaggle where citing datasets is discussed: https://www.kaggle.com/general/46091

Comment: hlw @Louic, Thank you. But I had a little bit confused about the format of the following citation. Because there might be a difference in IEEE conference format for the Kaggle dataset.